# C# MVC5 View dynamically filled Chart.js dont show up

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, chart.js

I am trying to implement a chart of the chart.js library into my view. However, i am not able to display the chart as desired.

The particular part in my razor view:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
            <p class="text-center">
            <strong>Energy Consumption and Production: 1 Jan, 2016 - 30 Jul, 2016</strong>
             </p>
             <div class="chart-responsive">
             <canvas id="trendChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
             </div> @*/.chart-responsive*@
```

My Javascript code regarding the line chart:

```
$(function () {

var datachart = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Consumption",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(215,220,67,0.3)",
            borderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.7)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            data: []
        },
        {
            label: "Production",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(90,193,208,0.3)",
            borderColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.7)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            data: []
        }
    ]
};

var trendChartOptions = {
    //Boolean - If we should show the scale at all
    showScale: true,
    //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
    scaleShowGridLines: false,
    //String - Colour of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
    //Number - Width of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
    //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
    scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
    //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
    scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
    //Boolean - Whether the line is curved between points
    bezierCurve: true,
    //Number - Tension of the bezier curve between points
    bezierCurveTension: 0.3,
    //Boolean - Whether to show a dot for each point
    pointDot: false,
    //Number - Radius of each point dot in pixels
    pointDotRadius: 4,
    //Number - Pixel width of point dot stroke
    pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,
    //Number - amount extra to add to the radius to cater for hit detection outside the drawn point
    pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
    //Boolean - Whether to show a stroke for datasets
    datasetStroke: true,
    //Number - Pixel width of dataset stroke
    datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
    //Boolean - Whether to fill the dataset with a color
    datasetFill: true,
    //String - A legend template
    legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span><%=datasets[i].label%></li><%}%></ul>",
    //Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>",
    //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
    responsive: true
};

$.getJSON("/AdminLte/GetData", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        datachart.labels.push(item._DATE);
        datachart.datasets[0].data.push(item.CONSUMPTION);
        datachart.datasets[1].data.push(item.PRODUCTION);
    })
});
var ctx = new Chart(document.getElementById("trendChart").getContext("2d")).Line(datachart, trendChartOptions);
```

});

And my controller method for dynamically filling the data:

```
public ContentResult GetData()
        {
            List<MeterDataTrendViewModel> meterDataTrend = new List<MeterDataTrendViewModel>();
            var result =
            from s in db.MeterDatas.ToList()
            group s by new { s._DATE } into g
            select new
                {
                read_date = g.Key._DATE,
                CONSUMPTION = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt64(x.CONSUMPTION)),
                PRODUCTION = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt64(x.PRODUCTION))
                };
            foreach(var res in result)
            {
                MeterDataTrendViewModel mdv = new MeterDataTrendViewModel();
                mdv._DATE = res.read_date;
                mdv.CONSUMPTION = res.CONSUMPTION.ToString();
                mdv.PRODUCTION = res.PRODUCTION.ToString();
                meterDataTrend.Add(mdv);
            }

            return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(meterDataTrend), "application/json");
        }
```

I`ve already debugged my js code and the data and labels array is filled correctly therefore my controller action is called. But there is only one datetime string displayed vertically so i guess it´s maybe aligned to the y-axis?

I can also fill the chart with static data and it´s displayed correctly. I cant figure out why my dynamic data isn´t displayed the right way.

Comment: What version of Chart.js are you using?

Comment: Version 1.0.1 as it comes with the bootstrap AdminLte template. But thanks, i will checkout v2!

Comment: Chart.js has been greatly improved in v2, so yes, I would suggest switching to that. You can check out the [Chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) to see how to properly set up your chart. Once you upgrade to v2, if you are still having this problem, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: after further investigation i've found out that chart.js is not the problem as the chart is displayed correctly when i debug my js file. Everything works fine aswell with static data. I think it´s something with the jquery getJSON, after i debug my chart js file the debugger jumps into some jquery fire methods and everything is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this problem on my own with the following modifications.

```
$.getJSON("/AdminLte/GetData", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                chartlabels[i] = item._DATE;
                cons[i] = item.CONSUMPTION;
                prod[i] = item.PRODUCTION;
            })
            var ctx = new Chart(document.getElementById("trendChart").getContext("2d")).Line(datachart, trendChartOptions);
        });
    });
```